# d3jsv4 timeline chart with vertical month axis during scrub

Tags: d3.js, timeline

I am trying to build a d3js timeline chart with axis grid lines vertically indicating the month region.

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/simple-scrollable-timeline-chart-with-d3-js-d3-timeline/
^ something like this featured some code - which I think is v3

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickSize(-height);
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')').call(xAxis);
```

my current implementation has failed.
https://jsfiddle.net/g89kuoe1/4/

these are the v4 methods to create axis -- but it needs to be repeated on the chart to formulate the grid lines.

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xRange).tickFormat(function(d){ return d.x;});
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yRange);
```

or should a new clip path be made to contain these lines - and add them as lines - with x1 values that hit each month?

[image]

Comment: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html  I've tried following this - but this looks like an old version of d3

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/c8gdfxob/
** SOLVED -- had to use minExtent and maxExtent -- and force the scale of the ticks to be a month

[image]
this creates non-moving vertical grid lines - but I am unsure how to adapt it to the codebase so they morph with the scrub

it maps the timeline months -- but doesn't flow with the morph..

```
 var scale = d3
   .scaleTime()
   .range([0, w])
   .domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);


 // Gridline
 var gridlines = d3.axisTop()
   .tickFormat("")
   .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
   .tickSize(-mainHeight)
   .scale(scale);

    main.selectAll(".grid").remove()

 main.append("g")
   .attr("class", "grid")
   .call(gridlines);
```